# How to use Retrofit to handle JSON in streaming format like on Twitter?

Tags: android, json, twitter, streaming, retrofit

I've got a stream containing endless JSON of events and I can't wait forever until it ends.

How can I show its data when it is still downloading (streaming)? Should I pause it/disconnect, so retrofit can see the entire JSON and pass it through to GSON? If yes, how can I do this using Retrofit? Possible example of such streaming could be an API from Twitter streaming.

I also fear about downloading too many events - how can I stop streaming, after some particular number of events?

Comment: there should be a parameter for limit in th twitterAPI

Comment: @meda there is no such parameter